# PHP OO Design: extend static class or instance class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static

I have an application which defines certain actions on common object types.

For example, you can have forum post and images. For each forum post and image you can do the following actions: recommend, comment, rate.

I have currently defined a static class

```
class CoreObjectUtil
{
    protected static $_objObjKey  = null;
    protected static $_objTypeKey = null;

    public static function getComments (...) {...}
    public static function getCommentsArray (...) {...}
    public static function getRatings (...) {...}
    public static function getRatingsArray (...) {...}
}
```

which is then subclassed like this

```
class ForumPostUtil extends CoreObjectUtil
{
    protected static $_objObjKey  = 'forumpost';
    protected static $_objTypeKey = 'FP';
}
```

to provide the relevant functionality for forum posts. The 2 parameters suffice to let the generic code in CoreObjectUtil know what to do for each object type for which these functions are applicable.

To use these functions, I am calling the selectPostProcess() class in my instance classes like this:

```
public function selectPostProcess ($data)
{
    $data = ForumPostUtil::mergeRatings ($data);
    $data = ForumPostUtil::mergeComments ($data);
    ...
}
```

This works well and keeps the main code centralized in the CoreObjectUtil class with its subclasses providing the data setup to let the code in CoreObjectUtil know what to do.

An alternative approach would be to move the code from CoreObjectUtil into a base instance class which is then inherited in my instance classes. So rather than calling static methods from CoreObjectUtil I would be doing method calls like $this->getComments().

Either approach would work just fine from a functionality type point of view. I'm wondering however what ObjectOriented design guidelines and experienced ObjectOriented developers think of these two approaches. Which way of doing this is preferable and why?

I would appreciate any thoughts/insights on this matter. I can code either way without problem, but I'm having a tough time deciding which route to take.

Comment: the general saying is: use objects, not static class functions. objects are much more flexible.

Comment: When you are making all-static class, it is not even OOP. The "class" actually acts like a namespace for variables and functions. Basically, this is just another form of procedural programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code you have now is, I think, the most procedural approach ever posing as OOP i.e what you have now is at the opposite side of OOP. Using the class keyword doesn't make it OOP.

First of all, you should forget about static, it's not that it's bad ot use but it's so easily abused that you really have to try first if the functionality can belong to an object modelling a domain concept (in your case forum related). Only if it doesn't make sense this way, you'll have it as a static method somewhere in  a utility class.

Truth be told you have to redesign yur app around the OOP mindset, that is to define classes with behaviour which model a specific concept or process and which have only one responsaiblity. More over you should not mix things like business objects (object which model the forum concepts) with persistence concerns i.e don't put in  the same object business functionality and database access. Use a separate class for accessing storage.

Use the Repository pattern to separate business layer from the persistence layer. Try not to mix together create/update functionality with querying IF it complicates things. Use a separate read model specifically for querying in that case.

The code you show us is about querying. You can have a simple DAO/Repository (call it what you want in this case) like this

```
 class ThreadViewData
 {
    public $Id ;
    public $Title;
    public $Comments; //etc
 }

  class ThreadsQueryRepository
  {
      //we inject the db access object , this helps with testing
      function _construct($db) { } 
       public function GetThread($id){ } //this returns a ThreadViewData
  }
```

The postPRocess functionality is a service that can Merge Ratings and Comments. But maybe the merge functionality is more suitable to the Rating and Comment objects. I don't know the domain to actually give a valid suggestion.

Point is, you have to think in objects not in functions and right now all you have is functions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I will redesign things according to the ideas you provided.